# Auto json binding not correctly done

Tags: grails, groovy

I have 3 domain classes : Foo, Bar & Com. The structure is :

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar
    Com com    
}

class Bar {
    String name    
}


class Com {
    String title    
}
```

Assuming that I have one Bar object with the ID 1 and one Com object with the ID 2, I'm doing the following JSON request :

```
{
    "bar" : {"id": 1},
    "com" : {"id": 2}
}
```

I want to update the Foo object with ID 1, so I typed :

```
def foo = Foo.get(1)
foo.properties = params
```

When I do that, the auto-binding isn't done correctly. I have to do it manually like this :

```
def foo = Foo.get(1)
foo.bar = Bar.get(params.bar.id)
foo.com = Com.get(params.com.id)
```

Why the binding isn't done correctly ? A clue ?

Best regards.

Comment: I assume your JSON data says "com" instead of "foo", correct?

Comment: Sure, it was a mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: Data binding doesn't take nested objects. You need `{ "bar.id" : 1, "com.id" : 2 }`